# Find early time divide by seconds/minutes/hourly

Tags: go

i have time divide by 240m or 4 hour. How to get early time divide by 4 hour starting 00.00 from random time or time.now() ?

- 02.35.00 will be 00.00.00
- 23.59.59 will be 20.00.00

Other sample. Divide by 50minutes:

- 00.50.00 will be 00.50.00
- 00.49.59 will be 00.00.00
- 01.50.00 will be 01.40.00...
- 23.59.59 will be 23.20.00

And divider can be starting from 1 second up to 23h59m.

I'm already kind of other approach like https://play.golang.org/p/oJn09DCWqjF but maybe it will be waste the memory of big slice and kind up slow performance if i want to use divider from 2/4 second. Because i want that for experiment expired cache without timer. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the approach you have tried in golang to regenerate the issue.

Comment: here my last approach https://play.golang.org/p/oJn09DCWqjF but it can't take fast if divider is seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`time.Time.Truncate`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Truncate) is mostly what you want.

It is a little tricky when the time comes with date though, since not all duration can devide 24 hours (for example 50 minutes). You will want to strip the date and add it back.

```
func truncate(t time.Time, d time.Duration) time.Time {
    yy, mm, dd := t.Date()
    t = t.AddDate(-yy, -int(mm), -dd)
    t = t.Truncate(d)
    t = t.AddDate(yy, int(mm), dd)
    return t
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/fFAqh_0Wkdp

Please note that playground has a fixed time.

Comment: Oh man you save my day, i didn't know there are Truncate func already available! because i dont need the date, so truncate only is doing as expected. i can divide from 1 second.